# IBOutlets are nil on iOS 8 devices, but work fine on iOS 9 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, nib, backwards-compatibility, iboutlet

When running iOS 8, the `IBOutlet`s of my nib based view controllers are `nil`, but when running iOS 9, they work fine. Any ideas why this might be happening?

My app supports iOS 8+, and I'm running Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 11):

The problem was in the way my UIViewController was instantiated. Changing
`let myVC = MyViewController()`

for
`let myVC = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)` fixed the problem.

Comment: Instead of passing `nil` for the bundle, you can use `NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would it be more accurate `NSBundle(forClass: MyViewController.self)`?

Comment: And even better: `let myVC = MyViewController(nibName: String(MyViewController), bundle: NSBundle(forClass: MyViewController.self))`

Comment: @jjramos: Has this stopped working with Xcode 7.3?  In my case I get this error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` while instantiating the View Controller as suggested above.  
I cannot work around this, despite adding explicit types, casts etc...

Comment: EDIT: I had added a custom init method. Adding an override for  `init(nibName:, bundle: )`  (and calling super in it) did it. Thanks!

Comment: In Swift 4: you can use `MyViewController(nibName: String(describing: MyViewController.self), bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))`